# Is there a way to have the mutation observer listen to the change in cascaded style of an element?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

For example I have an element say “span” which does not have a style attribute, but during runtime, the styles are cascaded and the span is decorated with some style(s) (say color/ font-size).

In this case the element itself does not have the style attribute. Can I configure mutation observer to listen to such changes?

The following does not work

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callBackFunc_);
var config = {attributes: true, attributeFilter: [“style”]};
mutationObserver.observe(this, config);
```